# BIRT Report Unable to run

Tags: eclipse, report, reporting, birt

I'm completely new to BIRT, but I'm trying to integrate it into some testing software. I downloaded the all-in-one package from eclipse for BIRT reporting (Windows 7, 64 bit). I've just started on my first report and I can't get the preview tab to display anything nor the web viewer. The only content on my report is a simple label. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's my source xml for the report:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
        <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.3.1.v201309091055 Build &lt;4.3.1.v20130917-1035></property>
        <property name="units">in</property>
        <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
        <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
        <property name="imageDPI">96</property>
        <styles>
            <style name="report" id="4">
                <property name="fontFamily">sans-serif</property>
                <property name="fontSize">10pt</property>
            </style>
            <style name="crosstab-cell" id="5">
                <property name="borderBottomColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderBottomWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderLeftColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderLeftStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderLeftWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderRightColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderRightStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderRightWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderTopColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderTopStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderTopWidth">1pt</property>
            </style>
            <style name="crosstab" id="6">
                <property name="borderBottomColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderBottomWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderLeftColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderLeftStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderLeftWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderRightColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderRightStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderRightWidth">1pt</property>
                <property name="borderTopColor">#CCCCCC</property>
                <property name="borderTopStyle">solid</property>
                <property name="borderTopWidth">1pt</property>
            </style>
        </styles>
        <page-setup>
            <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
                <page-footer>
                    <text id="3">
                        <property name="contentType">html</property>
                        <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                    </text>
                </page-footer>
            </simple-master-page>
        </page-setup>
        <body>
            <label id="7">
                <text-property name="text">BRIEF PRODUCT TEST REPORT</text-property>
            </label>
        </body>
    </report>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, seems like BIRT uses Internet Explorer to render the report and is apparently incompatible with Internet Explorer 11. Downgrading IE solved my problem

Comment: We can customize which web browser should be used by the webviewer. Got to window->preferences->Report design -> Preview -> Always use external browser

Comment: @dom you should make this an answer.